# Eigen: simplifying expression with Eigen intrinsics

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to scale all the columns in a matrix with a corresponding value from a vector. Where this value is 0, I want to replace that column with a column from an other matrix scaled by a constant. Sounds complicated, but in Matlab it's pretty simple (but probably not fully optimized):

```
a(:,b ~= 0) = a(:,b ~= 0)./b(b ~= 0);
a(:,b == 0) = c(:,b == 0)*x;
```

doing it with a `for loop` in C++ would also be pretty simple:

```
RowVectorXf b;
Matrix3Xf a, c;
float x;
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    if (b(i) != 0) {
        a.col(i) = a.col(i) / b(i);
    } else {
        a.col(i) = c.col(i) * x;
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to do this operation (faster) with Eigen intrinsics such as `colwise` and `select`?

p.s. I tried to shorten the if condition to the form

```
a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) / b(i)) : (c.col(i) * x);
```

But this does not compile with the error `error: operands to ?: have different types ...(long listing of the types)`

Edit:
I added the code for testing the answers, here it is:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

void flushCache()
{
    const int size = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // Allocate 20M. Set much larger than L2
    volatile char *c = (char *) malloc(size);
    volatile int i = 8;
    for (volatile int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        c[j] = i * j;

    free((void*) c);
}

int main()
{
    Matrix3Xf a(3, 1000000);
    RowVectorXf b(1000000);
    Matrix3Xf c(3, 1000000);
    float x = 0.4;

    a.setRandom();
    b.setRandom();
    c.setRandom();

    for (int testNumber = 0; testNumber < 4; testNumber++) {
        flushCache();
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int repetition = 0; repetition < 1000; repetition++) {
            switch (testNumber) {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
                        if (b(i) != 0) {
                            a.col(i) = a.col(i) / b(i);
                        } else {
                            a.col(i) = c.col(i) * x;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
                        a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) / b(i)).eval() : (c.col(i) * x).eval();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
                        a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) * (1.0f / b(i))) : (c.col(i) * x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    a = b.cwiseEqual(0.0f).replicate< 3, 1 >().select(c * x, a.cwiseQuotient(b.replicate< 3, 1 >()));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast< chrono::milliseconds >(t2 - t1).count();
        cout << "duration: " << duration << "ms" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output is:

```
duration: 14391ms
duration: 15219ms
duration: 9148ms
duration: 13513ms
```

By the way, not using setRandom to init the variables, the output is totally different:

```
duration: 10255ms
duration: 11076ms
duration: 8250ms
duration: 5198ms
```

@chtz suggests it's because of denormalized values, but I think it's because of branch prediction. An evidance that it's because of branch prediction is, that initializing `b.setZero();` leads to the same timings as not initializing.

Comment: Probably you need something like `.eval()` or `.finished()`.  Otherwise you have some weird expression template return types.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, appending `.eval()` to both expressions will make it work as well (`.finished()` is for the comma initializer).

Comment: I guess for a realistic benchmark you should also set some random elements of `b` to 0 -- otherwise getting 0 is very unlikely. And multiplying 3 elements by `1.f/b(i)` will of course be faster than dividing three elements by `b(i)`. I'm quite surprised about the results for the not-initialized variant, though (but that just proves never to blindly trust your intuition regarding benchmarking ...)

Comment: @chtz yes, with the 0's I totally agree. Concerning the division, I was hoping that it can be optimized away to a multiplication with the reciprocal. Possibly with -ffast-math it would.

Comment: In gcc/clang the flag `-freciprocal-math` should be sufficient to allow that. I would recommend to read about all effects of `-ffast-math` before using it. (It really depends on your use-case which optimization is ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) * (1.0f/b(i))) : (c.col(i) * x);
```

would work but only because the expressions would be of the same type, and it will likely not safe any time (a `? :` expression is essentially translated to the same as an `if`-`else` branch.)

If you prefer writing it into one line, the following expression should work:

```
a = b.cwiseEqual(0.0f).replicate<3,1>().select(c*x, a.cwiseQuotient(b.replicate<3,1>()));
```

Again, I doubt it will make any significant performance difference.

Comment: I did some measurements, on my pc (in a specific case) `a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) * (1.0f/b(i))) : (c.col(i) * x);` is about 10% faster than `a.col(i) = (b(i) != 0) ? (a.col(i) / b(i)).eval() : (c.col(i) * x).eval();`. Unfortunately `a = b.cwiseEqual(0.0f).replicate<3,1>().select(c*x, a.cwiseQuotient(b.replicate<3,1>()));` fails the assertion `aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()`. I'll add the code for testing to my question.

Comment: In your test code `b` is smaller than `a` and `c` by a factor of 10.

Comment: Also, for realistic comparisons, I recommend to initialize your matrices using `setRandom`, or even better with realistic values. Uninitialized matrices will contain unrealistic amounts of denormalized and non-finite values (which on almost all platforms influence the performance).

Comment: oh no... I'm sorry for that bug! Also thank you for the hint with setRandom. I did not use it, because it takes some time to init large matrices, but the effect is huge! The execution time of the first three tests is nearly the same, but the execution time of the last test is more than doubled! I'll add that to the queston, just in case someone is interested.

Comment: by the way, I do not think it's denormalized values, but rather branch prediction, that makes the difference in timing.